# Get Facebook username from email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the Facebook Graph API or FQL, how I can get the details of a user (name would be enough) given the user email? Is this possible? Users do not necessarily have to be my friends on Facebook.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at all. The `/search` endpoint does not provide such a functionality:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search